# Showing a Gaussian Kernel function is Lipschitz continuous and finding the the constant

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, lipschitz-functions

Consider the graph object in a d dimension space ($R^d$) so each node represents a vector of dimension d and we want to reweight the edges of the graph based on a gaussian kernel function.
Let a gaussian kernel function be defined as
$$
K(x_i,x_j)= e^{-\alpha*\left \| x_i-x_j \right \|^2} 
$$

where $x_i$ is a point in a $R^d$ space and we calculate the weight of ($x_i,x_j$) edge with function K.

The question that I want to address is I want to know that this function is a Lipshitz function or not.

I know the definition of Lipschitz continuous, but I don't know how to use it here. Has someone a hint?

Comment: $F$ is Lipschitz if $\|F(x) - F(y)\| \leq C(F)\|x-y\|$ for all $x,y$. In this case, would you like to prove that $K$ is Lipschitz in a single variable?

Comment: @rubikscube09 yes but the input of my function is a pair of nodes in d dimension space.